# Leetcode : Counting Elements with O(n) time Complexity

Tags: java

Given an integer array arr, count element x such that x + 1 is also in arr.If there're duplicates in arr, count them separately.

Example 1:
Input: arr = [1,2,3]
Output: 2
Explanation: 1 and 2 are counted cause 2 and 3 are in arr.

Example 2:
Input: arr = [1,1,2]
Output: 2
Explanation: 1 counted twice cause 2 is in arr.

Example 3:
Input: arr = [1,1,3,3,5,5,7,7]
Output: 0
Explanation: No numbers are counted, cause there's no 2, 4, 6, or 8 in arr.

Example 4:
Input: arr = [1,1,2,2]
Output: 2
Explanation: Two 1s are counted cause 2 is in arr.

MyCode : (Does not work for Example 2 only(for now))

```
int count = 0;
HashSet set = new HashSet();
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(set.contains(arr[i]-1) || set.contains(arr[i]+1)) {
        count++;
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }else {
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
return count;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you counting `arr[i]-1`?. The condition `set.contains(arr[i]+1)` is enough to count as per the definition.

I guess you are trying to achieve this in a single pass. This does not work because, you have to count the duplicate occurences as well.

Example 2 would work if the input was in a different order. ex: `[2,1,1]`.
your solution is more like counting the `arr[i]+1`s than counting such numbers itself.

Here's my code with 2 pass:

```cpp
class Solution {
    public int countElements(int[] arr) {
        Set<Integer> lookup = new HashSet<>();
        for(Integer i: arr){
            lookup.add(i);
        }
        
        int count =0;
        
        for(Integer i:arr){
            if(lookup.contains(i+1)){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

1. Add all elements to a set. This has complexity of O(n) and helps with O(1) lookup.
2. Iterate through the array and see if that element is present in the set. This has complexity of O(n) * O(1) viz O(n)

Although we are iterating the array twice, the time complexity will be O(n).

Comment: Thanks for answer .Yes ,I was trying to do with one pass but I guess it is not possible.

Comment: Adding elements to a set has log(n) complexity, so the overall solution has a n*log(n) complexity.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Adding elements to a set has the complexity of O(n). and The second loop runs n times and does operation of complexity of O(1). So its O(n) . I don't know what is making you think its O(nLogn) .

Answer (score 0):

Swift Solution O(n)

```
class Solution {
    func countElements(_ arr: [Int]) -> Int {
        var arrSet = Set(arr)
        var result = 0

        for num in arr {
            if arrSet.contains(num+1) {
                result += 1
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simple solution

````
class Solution:
    def countElements(self, arr: List[int]) -> int:
        c=0
        for i in arr:
         if(i+1 in arr):
                c+=1
        if(c>0):
            return c
        else:
            return 0```
````